# Convert grouped SQL statement to XML

Tags: c#, sql, xml

I have a requirement to take a string like this:

**[Pages] < '10' And [Pages] > '30' And ([Client.ShortName] = 'Test' Or [Review_Stage.Name] = 'Complete' Or ([ReviewCoreExt.ActiveReviewer] = 'ABC' And [Client.IsDemo] = 'True'))**

And convert it to XML like this:

```
<Filter>
    <FilterGroup ID="91140d9e-e805-4fa1-b86b-cdea197a279d" GroupType="And">
      <FilterCriteria ID="4950b1c8-cf04-48cb-be1a-247bbec5d2f7" MatchField="Pages" MatchType="Is Less Than" MatchValue="10" />
      <FilterCriteria ID="351f180d-0c65-430a-a64c-840c93d22a6e" MatchField="Pages" MatchType="Is Greater Than" MatchValue="30" />
      <FilterGroup ID="85662ed6-4377-434d-8185-cb52ec908a90" GroupType="Or">
        <FilterCriteria ID="c5698b82-678f-42a7-a917-c1388edf3274" MatchField="Client.ShortName" MatchType="Equals" MatchValue="Test" />
        <FilterCriteria ID="242746c6-013a-4f1c-9ace-efadeb5fdd9d" MatchField="Review_Stage.Name" MatchType="Equals" MatchValue="Complete" />
        <FilterGroup ID="cf8fcd62-b752-4b12-ae65-3f39fe9022f4" GroupType="And">
          <FilterCriteria ID="737cf486-e40b-47e4-8473-886e126d84a9" MatchField="ReviewCoreExt.ActiveReviewer" MatchType="Equals" MatchValue="ABC" />
          <FilterCriteria ID="abbfae00-2582-47b4-833a-bfaa0190fb9a" MatchField="Client.IsDemo" MatchType="Equals" MatchValue="True" />
        </FilterGroup>
      </FilterGroup>
    </FilterGroup>
  </Filter>
```

The Guid is just a new Guid(). Does anyone have a relatively simplistic method for doing something like this? Theoretically the groups can be nested an infinite number of times but in practice there are rarely more than 2-3 levels.

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 ways to do this:

1) Use a lexical analyzer. It'll request works, but you'll have something strong and will be able to "read" anything. [ANTLR](http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Antlr+3+CSharp+Target) is a lexical analyzer for .NET, you'll need to write how it'll decompose the words.

2) Write yourself a code that will split the sentence based on specific words (And, Or) then specific Operators (<, >, =, <=, >=). In your case it should be quite easy as the number of these words are quite limited.

You'll need to design a "Predicate" object: an object that have a left operand, an operator, and a right operand. Operand will be values, field, or Predicate (to allow recursivity in and/or).
From these split you build a list of the different Predicate, and once you've this tree it'll be easy to translate it into XML

I hope it give you the first steps in the right direction